# Reactjs - Component texteditor: all my text are editing at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a back-office where you can add / update / delete projects for a showroom.

When you want to add a new project, I have a model which open and display 4 languages.
Each language is a collapsing div onClick.

So I instantiate them this way in the render method of my main component:

```js
<Modal
    isOpen={this.state.addIsOpen}
    onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
    onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
    style={customStyles}
    contentLabel="Example Modal"
>
    <h2 ref="subtitle">Add a new Inspiration</h2>
    {
        languages.map((lang, i) => {
            return (
                <FormLanguage 
                    key={i}
                    lang={lang}
                />
            );
        })
    }
    <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Finish!</button>
</Modal>
```

The form language, another container is then instantiated this way:

```js
render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.addProject} style={{marginTop: 35, marginBottom: 50}}>
                <h2 onClick={this.expand}>{this.props.lang} language</h2>
                    <div style={{display: this.state.showMore ? "block" : "none"}}>
                        <label>
                            Title:<br />
                            <textarea value={this.state.titles.lang} onChange={this.handleTitle} />
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <label>
                            Description:<br />
                            <div style={{marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 20}}>
                                <RichEditorExample />
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
```

But then, when I try to type text, I figured out that all my textEditor are filling at the same time.

The render method of the texteditor (draftjs):

```js
return (
    <div className="RichEditor-root">
        <BlockStyleControls
            editorState={editorState}
            onToggle={this.toggleBlockType}
        />
        <InlineStyleControls
            editorState={editorState}
            onToggle={this.toggleInlineStyle}
        />
        <div className={className} onClick={this.focus}>
            <Editor
                blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
                customStyleMap={styleMap}
                editorState={editorState}
                handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onTab={this.onTab}
                ref="editor"
                spellCheck={true}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

With the constructor in charge of the onChange:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.focus = () => this.refs.editor.focus();
    this.onChange = (editorState) => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        dispatch(updateText(editorState));
    };
```

So, I'm like "damn, what am I missing here?".
Should I iterate inside of the form instead of doing it in the parent?

EDIT: 
As asked in the question, I'm following the Redux pattern, so here are the action / reducer methods:

```
export const UPDATE_TEXT = 'UPDATE_TEXT';

export function updateText(editorState) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_TEXT,
        editorState
    };
};
```

And the reducer:

```js
export function editorText(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_TEXT: 
            return action.editorState;
        default: 
            return state;
    };
};
```

Comment: The `updateText` method might be important here. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Yeah I'm following the Redux way, I just updated!

Comment: Don't you have one editorState for four editors? Isn't that related? http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/05/19/redux-reducer-arrays.html

Comment: I think you are right about that. Many thanks for the link!